# Почему только после второго нажатия на кнопку клиент отображает данные от сервера?

Tags: c++, qt, клиент-сервер, чат

Здраствуйте. Пишу клиент-серверный чат на Qt. Сервер берет с базы данных данные об юзере, его пароль и ник. Когда пользователь ввел в окно свои данные, сервер ищет юзера в БД, и отсылает сообщение клиенту "User is exists", если юзер уже существует. У клиента есть метод sockReady().

```
void LoginRegister::sockReady()
{
    Data = socket->readAll();
    QString text = QString(Data);
    qDebug()<<"from loginregister "<<text;
    if(text=="User is exists")
    {
        ui->lineEditMessage->setText("User is exists");
    }
}
```

Здесь просто на консоле отображает сообщение и в соотвествуещем lineEdit меняет текст. Этот lineEdit предназначен для вывода ошибки, как вот если такой юзер уже зарегестрирован.
Когда я ввела данные и нажимаю на кнопку REGISTER выполняеться данный код

```
    if(isValidName(user.getName()) && isValidPassword(user.getPassword())==-1)
    {
        //auto win = new firstwindow(this, 1);
        if(openForAction==2)//если была нажата кнопка регистрации
        {
            this->socket->write(QString("reg "+user.getName()+" "+user.getPassword()).toUtf8());
            if(ui->lineEditMessage->text()=="User is exists")
                qDebug()<<"USER IS EXISTS VXOD NEVOZMOZHEN";
        }
        else if(openForAction==1)
        {
            this->socket->write(QString("log "+user.getName()+" "+user.getPassword()).toUtf8());
        }
        //win->setAttribute( Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
        //win->show();
        //this->hide();
    }
```

Здесь сокет клиента отсылает данные о том что это реестрация, сервер обрабатывает эти данные, и по логике в методе sockReady обрабатываются данные полученные с сервера. И далее я просто проверяю, текст в моем lineEdit "User is exists" ? Да. (потому что ввожу уже существующего юзера, для наглядности примера). Но это условие не выполняеться с первого раза. Когда я нажимаю второй раз на кнопку Register, оно уже заходит в мое условие, и отображает "USER IS EXISTS VXOD NEVOZMOZHEN". Я не понимаю, почему только со второго раза это делается?
Помогите пожалуйста, скоро дедлайн, а я уже 3-й день над этой ошибкой сижу. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Вы знаете, я попытался вникнуть в код, есть несколько не совсем понятных моментов... Как Вы думаете, не может быть проблем из за того, что ответ из сокета приходит не мгновенно, а Вы его пытаетесь обработать в той же процедуре, котрая посылает на сервер запрос? ( и еще один лайвхак: если Вы переведете комментарии в коде на русский или английский - Вас здесь поймут больше людей )

Comment: спасибо, что откликнулись. а как тогда сделать так, чтобы этот ответ пришел? я пыталась делать это мютексами и тредами, но это не помогло. только после второго нажатия на кнопку появляються данные.

Comment: Видите, я не могу написать полноценный ответ, потому что по коду не могу полностью восстоздать картину. Но идея такая: 1) нажатие на кнопку - только посылает данные. 2) должна быть обработка события "данные пришли с сервера", и именно в этой обработке Вы меняете надпись на леблочке. Чтобы сделать второй пункт - Вам надо узнать, как обрабатывать событие "приход данных в сокет" - ну, просто поищите примеры такой обработки. Надеюсь, поможет! ( также, может быть, я не совсем въехал в задачу - никтоне застрахован от ошибок... )

Comment: у меня есть метод sockReady, это вроде и есть та обробка события "данные пришли с сервера"

Comment: Да, похоже, sockReady - это то, что нужно... Тогда разобраться довольно просто: ставим логгирование всего, что пришло в сокет, нажимаем на кнопку ОДИН раз - смотрим в лог... Потом думаем, что отличается в логе, если нажать на кнопку два раза.

Comment: Простой и хороший [пример](https://www.bogotobogo.com/Qt/Qt5_QTcpServer_Multithreaded_Client_Server.php). Думаю вам поможет

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо всем, я нашла ответ. В клиенте мы должны подождать ответа сервера, и это делается с помощью функции waitForReadyRead. Добавила одну строчку кода и все заработало!

```
if(socket.waitForReadyRead(15000)){
    //do something if signal is emitted
}
```

Comment: В этот момент ваш GUI не будет реагировать ни на какие действия, потому что все будут сидеть, вращать глазами, и ждать ответа от сервера (а если сервер занят? Переучет?). Но выход есть (сигналы-слоты) и если вам понадобится, вы можете воспользоваться сигналом установления соединения с сервером https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractsocket.html#connected, который сработает именно тогда когда сервер подтвердит соединения и ничего не будет фризиться

Comment: Вот совсем простенький пример (и, по-моему это то, что вы делаете) https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetwork-fortuneclient-example.html, а вот серверок для него https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetwork-fortuneserver-example.html. Все очень диетическое и нежное, на пару